# Gradle - Call parent file function from applied file

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I want to send to a separate file (script_a.gradle) some common logic across my gradle scripts, this file will have something as:

```
ext {
   something  getSomeValue()
}
```

where `getSomeValue()` was originally a function defined in the original gradle scripts.

So to have:

```
    apply from: 'script_a.gradle'

    static fun getSomeValue() {
       return "Parent1"
    }
    
    ...
    
    aValue = something   
    //the intention is that this performs script_a logic which in turn calls getSomeValue from this file
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your use-case is? but if you want to reuse some logic based on other scripts logic, You can do something like that:

```
val task1: TaskProvider<Task1> = tasks.register<Task1>("task1") { 
   outputDir.set(File(project.buildDir,"foo")) 
}

tasks.register<Task2>("task2"){ 
   inputDir.set(taskl.get().outputDir) 
}
```

you can have `task1` in `script.gradle` file and `task2` in another script file